# Kotlin: GSON fromJson doesn't compute

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I'm successfully receiving a JSON Object as request and passing it on to my parser. Code runs through until I call fromJson and then gets stuck. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the corresponding class:

```
class User(@SerializedName("mac") private val phoneMac: String) : Comparable<User> {

    @SerializedName("values")
    private val measurements: MutableSet<Measurement> = mutableSetOf()

    fun getPhoneMac(): String = phoneMac
    fun getMeasurements(): Set<Measurement> = measurements

    //etc.
}
```

Which refers to this class:

```
class Measurement (@SerializedName("mac") val deviceMac: String, val timestamp: String, val value: Double, val valueType: ValueType) : Comparable<Measurement>{

    fun getDeviceMac(): String = deviceMac
    fun getTimestamp(): String = timestamp
    fun getValue(): Double = value
    fun getValueType(): ValueType = valueType

        //etc.
}
```

And here is how I try to parse it:

```
fun fromJson(json: String): User {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
    builder.setPrettyPrinting()

    return builder.create().fromJson(json, User::class.java)
}
```

Had the fromJson-function spreaded out to make sure where it gets stuck: create() still works, fromJson() doesn't

Also, I know that the JSON file is correct and doesn't contain missing values or nulls.

For verification:

```
{
"mac": "00-80-41-ae-fd-b1",
"values": 
[
    {
    "mac": "ab-cd-ef-98-76-13",
    "timestamp": "2012-04-23T18:25:43",
    "value": 68,
    "valuetype": "HR"
    },
    {
    "mac": "ab-cd-ef-98-76-13",
    "timestamp": "2012-04-23T18:35:43",
    "value": 65,
    "valuetype": "HR"
    }
]
}
```

**Edit**: for clarification as to what I mean with my code getting stuck
For debugging purposes, I changed my fromJson function to look like this:

```
fun fromJson(json: String): User {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
    builder.setPrettyPrinting()

    println("json received")
    val gson = builder.create()
    println("GSON created")
    val user = gson.fromJson(json, User::class.java)
    println("user created")

    return user
}
```

My Console reads

> json received
>   GSON created

Meaning "user created" is not printed, therefore the gson.fromJson-call never returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the fix was to get rid of getter functions in Measurement-class or setting the fields in Measurement-class private.

I copy/pasted barsju's code, and it worked. So step by step tried to swap in pieces of my code. After swapping in my Measurments-class, I got the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate method name "getDeviceMac" with signature "()Ljava.lang.String;" in class file jsonStuff/Measurement

Did some experimentation and research only to find that if the fields of Measurement are not private but still have getter functions explicitly declared, they're recognized as duplicate functions, basically killing the application

Comment: Yes, a public val in the constructor will compile down to a field with a getter producing exactly the same outcome as your code. In kotlin you should generally never need to specify getters and setters manually. Only when you need to do computations or something clever do you need to do that. Also try reading up on data classes and immutability. It's going to save you from a lot of avoidable bugs and help improve your design.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by getting stuck, but this seems to work:

```
import com.google.gson.*
import com.google.gson.annotations.*

data class User(@SerializedName("mac") val phoneMac: String, @SerializedName("values") val measurements: MutableSet<Measurement>)

enum class ValueType{
    HR
}

data class Measurement (@SerializedName("mac") val deviceMac: String, val timestamp: String, val value: Double, val valuetype: ValueType)

fun fromJson(json: String): User {
    val builder = GsonBuilder()
    builder.setPrettyPrinting()

    return builder.create().fromJson(json, User::class.java)
}

fun main() {
    println(fromJson("""
        {
        "mac": "00-80-41-ae-fd-b1",
        "values": 
        [
            {
            "mac": "ab-cd-ef-98-76-13",
            "timestamp": "2012-04-23T18:25:43",
            "value": 68,
            "valuetype": "HR"
            },
            {
            "mac": "ab-cd-ef-98-76-13",
            "timestamp": "2012-04-23T18:35:43",
            "value": 65,
            "valuetype": "HR"
            }
        ]
        }
    """.trimIndent()))
}
```

Comment: I edited my original question to clarify what I mean by getting stuck. Also I tried to alter the json-String I use to not use any whitespaces, linebreaks or anything like that (to accomodate trimIndent(), which didn't change anything for me) with no effect.
However, I messed up cleaning my json String briefly, which led to an exception due to malformed json, so at least I can 100% confirm that gson.fromJson() is being called

Comment: I tried copy/pasting your code for test purposes. It works, but I fail to see how it differs from what I'm already doing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if you can, use [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), and remove the getters and the Comparable as well.
Also that's one of the differences of the example answers some of the users gave you here.